# How can i solve route.params is undefined?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

i have this part in my code, i want to test, but when i run the test route.params sound like the wrong:

```
 onMounted(async () => {
        try {
          const { tokenId } = route.params
```

it i used to get the id from url, but at the moment to test it

i am getting this error
Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

this is my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(App, {
    mocks: {
      route: {
          params: {
            id: 'id'
          }
        }
    },
    global: {
      plugins: [store],
    },
    computed: { notFound: () => {} },
  })
})
```

Comment: route or $route ?

Comment: @jeremycastelli is route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mocks.route` does ***not*** mock

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
//...

setup() {
  const route = useRoute();
  //...
}
```

You might want to have a look at examples presented [here](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vue-router.html) for a detailed approach on how to test various router related scenarios with a vue3 composition api setup.

---

To simply make your component not fail when `useRoute()` returns undefined, you could use this:

```
const { tokenId } = route?.params || {};
if (tokenId) {
  // do your thing...
}
```

There's no need for `try`.

---

To test that your component does what it's supposed to based on `tokenId` route param value, then you should mock `vue-router` in your test, to return a function returning a params object:

This should work:

```
jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRoute: () => ({ params: { id: 'id' } })
}));
```